# Combined multiple operations in R using DPLYR

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use DPLYR to retrieve and summarize data.  I wrote the below and it works, but I would like to combine this all into one statement.  Is this possible?

create datasets

```
set.seed(1)
dbo_games <- data.frame(
  name = sample(c("Team1","Team2","Team3","Team4","Team5","Team6","Team7","Team8","Team9","Team10")),
  total_games = sample(1:10)

)

set.seed(1)
dbo_wins <- data.frame(
  name = sample(c("Team1","Team2","Team3","Team4","Team5","Team6","Team7","Team8","Team9","Team10")),
  tota_wins = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)
```

```
total_games <- con %>% tbl("dbo_games")
total_wins <- con %>% tbl("dbo_wins")

total<- total_games %>% filter(games > 12) %>%
  group_by(NAME) %>%
  summarise(total_games = n_distinct(game_id)) %>% collect()

wins <- total_wins %>% filter( win == 'Y') %>%
  group_by(NAME) %>%
  summarise(total_wins = n_distinct(game_id)) %>% collect()

perc_win <- total %>% left_join(wins) %>%
  mutate(pct_won = total_wins/total_games)
```

This code works, but I believe there is likely a more succinct way of writing the code to achieve the same results.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I think I can, but I need some data.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. If we don't have sample data, it's not really reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been easier to address this if you had shared sample data and why you are doing what you are doing.

However, you could still chain them together as below:

```
total_games %>%
  filter(games > 12) %>%
  group_by(NAME) %>%
  summarise(total_games = n_distinct(game_id)) %>%
  left_join(total_wins %>% filter( win == 'Y') %>%
              group_by(NAME) %>%
              summarise(total_wins = n_distinct(game_id))) %>%
  mutate(pct_won = total_wins/total_games)
```